# Add text inside leaflet rectangle

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using the following code to create a rectangle in the `leaflet` map.

```
const rectangles = [[51.49, -0.08], [51.5, -0.06]]   

<Rectangle key={key} bounds={rectangle} color="green">

</Rectangle>
```

I want to add a text inside the rectangle like a label for the rectangle is there a way to do this?

I'm using [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/v1/examples.html) library for this.

Comment: What module/library are you using? Could you please add more info to your question? Are you using some react wrapper for leaflet ?

Comment: @agent_hunt I have added the library i'm using

Answer (score 8):

To write on the map, we can use a [DivIcon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#divicon) from the Leaflet library added to a React-Leaflet [Marker](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#marker) component.

### Create a DivIcon with HTML

A `DivIcon` is an icon that can contain HTML instead of an image. We'll import the `Leaflet` library and create a `DivIcon` with our desired text.

```js
import L from 'leaflet';

const text = L.divIcon({html: 'Your HTML text here'});
```

### Add the DivIcon to a Marker

With the `DivIcon` created, we'll add it to a Marker placed in the center of a `Polygon`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { Marker, Polygon } from 'react-leaflet';

const PolygonWithText = props => {
  const center = L.polygon(props.coords).getBounds().getCenter();
  const text = L.divIcon({html: props.text});

  return(
    <Polygon color="blue" positions={props.coords}>
      <Marker position={center} icon={text} />
    </Polygon>
  );
}

export default PolygonWithText
```

### Add the Marker to the Map

Finally, we add the `Polygon`, `Marker`, and `DivIcon` to a `Map`.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, TileLayer} from 'react-leaflet';
import PolygonWithText from './PolygonWithText';

class MyMap extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Map center={[20.75, -156.45]} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
        <PolygonWithText text="MyText" coords={[...]} />
      </Map>
  }
}

export default MyMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

refer the below code, this one uses a rectangle with a tooltip  inside it

> {zoneLabel}
>
> ```
> <Rectangle key={key} bounds={coordinates}>
> </Rectangle>
> ```