# How to add text inside polygon in vue-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I want to add text on the center of polygon feature in maps.
I was referred to the [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856182/add-text-inside-leaflet-rectangle) and I made code like that.

```
<template>
  <l-map style="height: 350px" :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
    <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
    <l-polygon :lat-lngs="polygon.latlngs" :color="polygon.color">
      <l-marker
        :lat-lngs="polygonCenter(polygon.latlngs)"
        :icon="polyGonText"
      ></l-marker>
    </l-polygon>
  </l-map>
</template>

<script>
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LPolygon, LMarker } from "vue2-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";

export default {
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LPolygon,
    LMarker,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a target="_blank" href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      zoom: 8,
      center: [47.31322, -1.319482],
      polygon: {
        latlngs: [
          [47.2263299, -1.6222],
          [47.21024000000001, -1.6270065],
          [47.1969447, -1.6136169],
          [47.18527929999999, -1.6143036],
          [47.1794457, -1.6098404],
          [47.1775788, -1.5985107],
          [47.1676598, -1.5753365],
          [47.1593731, -1.5521622],
          [47.1593731, -1.5319061],
          [47.1722111, -1.5143967],
          [47.1960115, -1.4841843],
          [47.2095404, -1.4848709],
          [47.2291277, -1.4683914],
          [47.2533687, -1.5116501],
          [47.2577961, -1.5531921],
          [47.26828069, -1.5621185],
          [47.2657179, -1.589241],
          [47.2589612, -1.6204834],
          [47.237287, -1.6266632],
          [47.2263299, -1.6222],
        ],
        color: "green",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    polygonCenter(latlngs) {
      return L.polygon(latlngs).getBounds().getCenter();
    },
    polyGonText() {
      return L.divIcon({ html: "No.1" });
    },
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.polygon
      .bindTooltip("My Text", { permanent: true, direction: "center" })
      .openTooltip();
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

[my sample code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/polygon-test-6d5lm?file=/App.vue)

my code is referred to [vue-leaflet site](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/components/LPolygon.html#demo), and just add methods to get center of polygon "latLang" and set html object.
But html text(No.1) is not shown on the polygon.
How can I add text in to the polygon?
Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach text to a polygon using tooltip, like this:

```
polygon.bindTooltip("My Text",
    {permanent: true, direction:"center"}
).openTooltip()
```

Edit:

I looked at your code and you're attaching **bindTooltip()** and **openTooltop()** functions to an object, this is incorrect.
What you need to do is to attach these functions to an Leaflet **mapObject**.

Here's the code you need to update:

```
//template
<l-polygon ref="poly" :lat-lngs="polygon.latlngs" :color="polygon.color">
//mounted
mounted: function () {
   this.$nextTick(() => {
        const poly = this.$refs.poly.mapObject;
        poly.bindTooltip("My Text", { permanent: true, direction: "center" }).openTooltip();
});
```

Also you should really use pure leaflet library, if you learn it once you'll be able to use it everywhere, does not matter if it is react, vue or pure js.

Comment: thank you for the comments. I tried to add your advise in my code and edit my question' code and sandbox. But nothing change, I think I misunderstand your advise. Would you check my question code or sandbox, please?

Comment: @drunkdolphin I edited my anwers

Comment: Thank you for your advise and answer. I try to use pure leaflet library. Thanks a lot!